# Why can't I call a package-private method of another class that's a subclass of a class in the same package?

Tags: java, package, visibility

I have a class `Base` in package A that defines the package-private method `foo()`.  In package B, I have a class `Impl` that extends `Base`.  In package A, if I try to call `foo()` on an instance of `Impl`, I get a compiler error.  (However, I can cast `Impl` to `Base` and then call it.)

It seems reasonable that I should be able to call `foo()` from within the package, even if the object I'm calling it on is defined outside the package.  Is there a good reason that I can't?

Answer (score 0):

You gave the answer yourself. The state "package private" of method foo() in class A of package A doesn't end just because you extend this class. As long as the extending class B derives from a different package B, the compiler will throw an error if you try to access method foo() in class A of package A.

> *Is there a good reason that I can't?*

Because it's a rule of Java's.